# Nagios: NRPE unable to read output

Tags: nagios, nrpe

I really hope that someone can provide a solution for me. I have check_memory to check my remote hosts, but no matter what I try, I keep getting "NRPE unable to read output" on the Nagios dashboard.

My nrpe.cfg:

`command[check_memory]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_memory -w 90 -c 5 -f`

My service check .cfg

```
define service {
        use                             generic-service
        host_name                       host.server.local
        service_description             Memory Usage
        check_command                                  check_nrpe!check_memory!
}
```

memory_check file located in /usr/local/nagios/libexec from: [exchange.nagios](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/Linux/check_memory-2Esh/details)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#Set script name
SCRIPT=`basename ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`

#Set default values
optMW=95
optMC=98
optSW=95
optSC=98

# help function
function printHelp {
  echo -e \\n"Help for $SCRIPT"\\n
  echo -e "Basic usage: $SCRIPT -w {warning} -c {critical} -W {warning} -C {critical}"\\n
  echo "Command switches are optional, default values for warning is 95% and critical is 98%"
  echo "-w - Sets warning value for Memory Usage. Default is 95%"
  echo "-c - Sets critical value for Memory Usage. Default is 98%"
  echo "-W - Sets warning value for Swap Usage. Default is 95%"
  echo "-C - Sets critical value for Swap Usage. Default is 98%"
  echo -e "-h  - Displays this help message"\\n
  echo -e "Example: $SCRIPT -w 80 -c 90 -W 40 -C 60"\\n
  exit 1
}

# regex to check is OPTARG an integer
re='^[0-9]+$'

while getopts :w:c:W:C:h FLAG; do
  case $FLAG in
    w)
      if ! [[ $OPTARG =~ $re ]] ; then
        echo "error: Not a number" >&2; exit 1
      else
        optMW=$OPTARG
      fi
      ;;
    c)
      if ! [[ $OPTARG =~ $re ]] ; then
        echo "error: Not a number" >&2; exit 1
      else
        optMC=$OPTARG
      fi
      ;;
    W)
      if ! [[ $OPTARG =~ $re ]] ; then
        echo "error: Not a number" >&2; exit 1
      else
        optSW=$OPTARG
      fi
      ;;
    C)
      if ! [[ $OPTARG =~ $re ]] ; then
        echo "error: Not a number" >&2; exit 1
      else
        optSC=$OPTARG
      fi
      ;;
    h)
      printHelp
      ;;
    \?)
      echo -e \\n"Option - $OPTARG not allowed."
      printHelp
      exit 2
      ;;
  esac
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))





array=( $(cat /proc/meminfo | egrep 'MemTotal|MemFree|Buffers|Cached|SwapTotal|SwapFree' |awk '{print $1 " " $2}' |tr '\n' ' ' |tr -d ':' |awk '{ printf("%i %i %i %i %i %i %i", $2, $4, $6, $8, $10, $12, $14) }') )

memTotal_k=${array[0]}
memTotal_b=$(($memTotal_k*1024))
memFree_k=${array[1]}
memFree_b=$(($memFree_k*1024))
memBuffer_k=${array[2]}
memBuffer_b=$(($memBuffer_k*1024))
memCache_k=${array[3]}
memCache_b=$(($memCache_k*1024))
memTotal_m=$(($memTotal_k/1024))
memFree_m=$(($memFree_k/1024))
memBuffer_m=$(($memBuffer_k/1024))
memCache_m=$(($memCache_k/1024))
memUsed_b=$(($memTotal_b-$memFree_b-$memBuffer_b-$memCache_b))
memUsed_m=$(($memTotal_m-$memFree_m-$memBuffer_m-$memCache_m))
memUsedPrc=$((($memUsed_b*100)/$memTotal_b))

swapTotal_k=${array[5]}
swapTotal_b=$(($swapTotal_k*1024))
swapFree_k=${array[6]}
swapFree_b=$(($swapFree_k*1024))
swapUsed_k=$(($swapTotal_k-$swapFree_k))
swapUsed_b=$(($swapUsed_k*1024))
swapTotal_m=$(($swapTotal_k/1024))
swapFree_m=$(($swapFree_k/1024))
swapUsed_m=$(($swapTotal_m-$swapFree_m))

if [ $swapTotal_k -eq 0 ]; then
    swapUsedPrc=0
else
    swapUsedPrc=$((($swapUsed_k*100)/$swapTotal_k))
fi

message="[MEMORY] Total: $memTotal_m MB - Used: $memUsed_m MB - $memUsedPrc% [SWAP] Total: $swapTotal_m MB - Used: $swapUsed_m MB - $swapUsedPrc% | MTOTAL=$memTotal_b;;;; MUSED=$memUsed_b;;;; MCACHE=$memCache_b;;;; MBUFFER=$memBuffer_b;;;; STOTAL=$swapTotal_b;;;; SUSED=$swapUsed_b;;;;"


if [ $memUsedPrc -ge $optMC ] || [ $swapUsedPrc -ge $optSC ]; then
  echo -e $message
  $(exit 2)
elif [ $memUsedPrc -ge $optMW ] || [ $swapUsedPrc -ge $optSW ]; then
  echo -e $message
  $(exit 1)
else
  echo -e $message
  $(exit 0)
fi
```

my tar -f /var/log/messages:

```
nagios nagios: SERVICE NOTIFICATION: admins;host.server.local;Memory Usage;UNKNOWN;notify-service-by-email;NRPE: Unable to read output
```

When I do a "force" check, /var/log/messages shows the following:

```
nagios nagios: EXTERNAL COMMAND: SCHEDULE_FORCED_SVC_CHECK;host.server.local;Memory Usage;1612190795
```

My manual check on command line on remote host:

```
[root@host libexec]# ./check_memory -w 80 -c 95
[MEMORY] Total: 1828 MB - Used: 360 MB - 19% [SWAP] Total: 2047 MB - Used: 0 MB - 0% | MTOTAL=1917046784;;;; MUSED=376434688;;;; MCACHE=119762944;;;; MBUFFER=2158592;;;; STOTAL=2147479552;;;; SUSED=0;;;;
```

Manual check on nagios server:

```
[root@nagios libexec]# ./check_nrpe -H host check_memory
NRPE v4.0.3
```

If anyone can please point out what I'm doing wrong, I will appreciate it. Let me know if any other info required.

Comment: https://support.nagios.com/kb/article/nrpe-nrpe-unable-to-read-output-620.html "This error implies that NRPE did not return any character output. Common causes are incorrect plugin paths in the nrpe.cfg file or that the remote host does not have NRPE installed. There are also cases where the wrong interpreter is invoked when running the remote plugin. Rarely, it is caused by trying to run a plugin that requires root privileges." -- please check all of these and add the output to your question.

Answer (score 0):

check as which user NRPE daemon is running and relaunch the script from command line under that user.

Comment: see my post above. Thank you

Comment: `su nagios -s /bin/sh -c '/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_memory -w 90 -c 5 -f'` or
`sudo -u nagios /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_memory -w 90 -c 5 -f`